# Connecting Pentaho to Apache Druid

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, druid, pentaho-cde

Can anybody let me know the steps to connect to Apache Druid using Tableau, please?

I tried the following steps:

1. Copy the Avatica jar file to tomcat/lib
2. Create a new Generic Database (JDBC connection) using the following parameters options-

> ```
> MSTR_JDBC_JAR_FOLDER=/opt/mstr/MicroStrategy/install/JDBC;
> DRIVER=org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Driver;
> URL={jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://localhost:8082/druid/v2/sql/avatica/};
> ```

Note- 
1. userid/password is not enabled i.e. Druid can be accessed without login credentials

2. Able to access the Druid console "http://localhost:8888/unified-console.html"
3. Able to connect to Druid using Apache Superset and Tableau applications.

Answer (score 0):

jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://localhost:8082/druid/v2/sql/avatica/

instead of HTTP replace it with druid. like I did below , may be it works.

jdbc:avatica:remote:url=druid://localhost:8082/druid/v2/sql/avatica/

Also let me know the update that were you able to connect druid to pentaho